# query with a field in several conditions in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I need to make a query like this:

```
db.subscribers.find({LISTID: 59, {$or: [{LANG: {$in: ['English', 'Spanish']} }, 
                                        {LANG: {$nin: ['Russian']} }]}  });
```

It's supposed to get all subscribers from listid 59, who know English or Spanish or(and) doesn't know Russian. Instead of language there could be any field that can have multiple values.
It looks like this query works in mongodb console.
In this case one field can be in several conditions.
I there is the same field wouldn't be in several conditions, maybe it could be something like:

```
$collection->find(array('LISTID' => $listId, 
                        array('$or' = array(LANG => array('$in' =>  array('English','Spanish')),

/*some other condition united with OR*/
                                                                        )));
```

How to make this query in php?

Comment: Why do you write: "list id = 59 OR LANG != 'Russian", it should be AND.

Comment: It's necessary to find all subscribers from listid = 59, who knows English or Spanish and don't know Chinese, for example.

Comment: I don't see any nonse in the question at all. Do you see? Could you explain what issues do you see with it?

Comment: `$or [LANG in (), LANG not in ('Russian')]` will match any language except Russian - irrespective of what `in ()` is because everything matches "not Russian" . Your php code has parse errors - basically there's no way you want to execute that query or used the code in the question. Anyways - good luck.

Comment: Maybe it is not quite good, for example, instead of OR it could be AND. It doesn't matter. The question is how to use one field in several conditions, like LANG in the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's supposed to get all subscribers from listid 59, who know English or Spanish and doesn't know Chinese.

If that's the objective of your query (I assume you mean "Russian" instead of "Chinese"), I don't see how your original console query works:

```
db.subscribers.find({
    LISTID: 59,
    { $or: [
        { LANG: { $in: ["English", "Spanish"] } },
        { LANG: { $nin: ["Russian"] } }
    ] }
});
```

`$or` needn't be nested in its own object according to the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or). Also, if you're looking for documents with a given LISTID that know two languages but not another, `$and` seems more appropriate:

```
db.subscribers.find({
    LISTID: 59,
    $and: [
        { LANG: { $in: ["English", "Spanish"] } },
        { LANG: { $ne: "Russian" } }
    ]
});
```

This would translate to PHP as:

```
$collection->find(array(
    'LISTID' => $listId,
    '$and' => array(
        array('LANG' => array('$in' => array('English', 'Spanish'))),
        array('LANG' => array('$ne' => 'Russian')),
    ),
));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant: "It's supposed to get all subscribers from listid 59, who know English or Spanish or(and) doesn't know Russian." I corrected my post.

Comment: It seems $or works as nested. In any cases thank you for you remark about nested $or.

Comment: The question was about php code. I think I answer this question in the first answer. If you have any sugguestions about php, you could also give your php code, maybe you could see any issues with my answer.

Comment: I just realized I made a typo with the `$and` example. Just edited to remove the `{}` wrapping. Also added a PHP translation, which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes, it's the same solution as my own answer. In any case, thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is something like this:

```
$number = $collection->find(array('LISTID' => $listId, 
                                  '$or' => array( array('LANG' => array('$in' => array('English', 'Spanish'))),
                                                  array('LANG' => array('$nin' => array('Russian'))),
                                                ) ))->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Find record according to specific column
$getfollower = $dbnew1->find(array('follower' => $follower),
                             array('page_name' => 1, 'id'=>1, '_id'=>0));
```